# Use case for Neovim terminal mode inside tmux session

Tags: neovim

Now that we have terminal mode in neovim, I am wondering if there is still a use case for tmux. Let's say that I need to work on a remote machine using SSH. In order to keep a persistent vim session, I would launch a tmux session on the remote machine, start neovim and create as many terminal windows as needed. I don't need to use the windowing mechanism of tmux anymore. Are there any use cases that neovim terminal mode cannot satisfy?

Answer (score 6):

tmux provides session management.  For example, you can create multiple sessions and then detach/re-attach as you please.  With terminal emulation in neovim, the shell is killed when the terminal buffer is closed.  So, there's still a use-case for it, however, the *primary* use case with regards to vim + tmux has been eliminated with terminal emulation.